# Rails 3 update scope with conditions, include, and args to Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading a Rails 3 code base to Rails 4 and have been updating to use the new scope style and querying interface.

I'm unsure how to switch over this scope that is using include as well as conditions in the scope's lambda.

```
  scope :search_stuff, lambda { |search|
    search_conditions = Array.new(4, "%#{search}%")
    {
      :include => {:sponsor => [], :routing_form_pi_users => [:user], :item => []},
      :conditions => ["id like ? or title like ? or users.name like ? or sponsors.name like ?", *search_conditions]
    }
  }
```

Comment: What is your problem? What did you try? Does it not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

When you compare the documentation about the query interface in different versions of the Rails Guide then you can see that the interface for eager loading of multiple associations didn't change that much.

The example in [Rails 2.3.8](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) syntax:

```
Category.find 1, :include => {:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags]}
```

The example for [Rails 4.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations) syntax:

```
Category.includes(articles: [{ comments: :guest }, :tags]).find(1)
```

Therefore it should be possible to just copy the old nested hash into the new syntax:

```
scope :search_stuff, lambda { |search|
  includes(item: [], routing_form_pi_users: [:user], sponsor: []).
    where('id like ? or title like ? or users.name like ? or sponsors.name like ?', *Array.new(4, "%#{search}%"))
}
```